# CakePHP Bake Shell Error: Database connection “Mysql” is missing, or could not be created

Tags: php, cakephp, pdo, command-line-interface, cakephp-bake

I have an issue here with baking.
I've read the previous answers to similar questions, but the solutions seem to not apply here.

I can't bake because the error I receive is: `Database connection “Mysql” is missing, or could not be created`

If I run `which php` the PHP it's reading is the correct path within MAMP.

If I check the PDO modules:

```
php -i | grep "PDO"
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, pgsql, mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

My application (or what I've completed on it so far) has no trouble connecting to the database.

All answers around the web point to PDO not being enabled, or the incorrect path for PHP, but neither of those apply in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a wrong username / password or misspelled database name. I once had a database (name) beginning with a space.

You may want to check the database connection using plain PHP, [see](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Comment: You are a lifesaver - I have an FTP connection in netbeans, and the connection was still pointing to my online database instead of my local (as required by bake). Thanks mate... I'd thought the problem was deeper routed than that.

Comment: Or another database, I made a copy of the database and I got that error. This error is due to a bad (not updated, misspelled, ...) configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution (Mac and MAMP) is to update your database connection HOST. I had specified *localhost* and received this error message. When I updated the host to *127.0.0.1* cake was able to make the connection.

The symlink method described by cfkane should also address the issue.

Comment: It was localhost vs 127.0.0.1 (use the IP, or else specify a unix socket) for me. What's bizarre is that it was working fine with localhost for a while. I don't know what I could've changed.

Comment: this worked for me with XAMPP and MacOS X - went into database.php and changed localhost to '127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 3):

I finally found out what was the problem, at least for me:
In database.php, I specified:

```
'encoding' => 'utf-8'
```

whereas:

```
'encoding' => 'utf8'
```

would be much better !

In order to save time to users, I suggest the exception handler could display the full error message from PDO. Here is my patch:

```
--- a/lib/Cake/Error/exceptions.php
+++ b/lib/Cake/Error/exceptions.php
@@ -378,7 +378,7 @@ class MissingDatabaseException extends CakeException {
  */
 class MissingConnectionException extends CakeException {

-       protected $_messageTemplate = 'Database connection "%s" is missing, or could not be created.';
+       protected $_messageTemplate = "Database connection \"%s\" is missing, or could not be created:\n    %s";

        public function __construct($message, $code = 500) {
                if (is_array($message)) {
```

The result is:

```
[default] > 
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created:
    SQLSTATE[42000] [1115] Unknown character set: 'utf'
#0 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(262): Mysql->connect()
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue while using MAMP on MacOS.

From the command prompt, I had to run this sudo

> sudo mkdir /var/mysql

Then this one

> sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Then when I ran my cake bake command again, everything worked.

Found that here: http://www.mojowill.com/developer/quick-tip-cakephp-baking-and-mamp/

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem, checked PDO support the same way, same result.

The following script (that I wrote) might help to make sure our settings are ok:

```php
<?php
include("../new-project/app/Config/database.php");
$config= new DATABASE_CONFIG();

$name = 'default';

$settings=$config->{$name};
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$settings['database'].';host='.$settings['host'];
$user = $settings['login'];
$password = $settings['password'];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    echo "Connection succeeded with dsn: ". $dsn . "\n";
    $sql = 'SELECT id, title FROM posts';
    echo "Here is the contents of the table `posts:";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['id'] . "\t" . $row['title'] . "\n";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'PDO error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

And it works fine :

```
mich@dennet:~/www/learn/cakePHP/tools$ php test-pdo.php
Connection succeeded with dsn: mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost
Here is the contents of the table `posts:1  The title
3   Title strikes back
4   Once again is back
```

FYI, here are version details :

```
mich@dennet:~/www/learn/cakePHP/tools$ php --version
PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2013 19:32:25)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.0dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

Would it be a problem with paths ? Here's my bake interaction:

```
mich@dennet:~/www/learn/cakePHP/new-project$ /usr/local/bin/cake -app  /home/mich/www/learn/cakePHP/new-project/app bake

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.1 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /home/mich/www/learn/cakePHP/new-project/app/
...
What would you like to Bake? (D/M/V/C/P/F/T/Q)
> m
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake Model
Path: /home/mich/www/learn/cakePHP/new-project/app/Model/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Use Database Config: (default/forbaking)
[default] >
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
#0 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(262): Mysql->connect()
#1 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(107): DboSource->__construct(Array)
#2 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(927): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
#3 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(864): ModelTask->getAllTables(NULL)
#4 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(953): ModelTask->listAll(NULL)
#5 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(205): ModelTask->getName()
#6 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(93): ModelTask->_interactive()
#7 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/BakeShell.php(111): ModelTask->execute()
#8 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(435): BakeShell->main()
#9 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(210): Shell->runCommand(NULL, Array)
#10 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(68): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#11 /usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp/app/Console/cake.php(37): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#12 {main}
```

I also tried :

```
mich@dennet:/usr/local/share/cakePHP/cakephp$ app/Console/cake bake
```

with no more success.

Now I suspect the Datasource itself ...

HTH

Michelle

Answer (score 0):

Just to help **Ubuntu** users out:
I had the same error in my ubuntu 13.10 machine with the newest xampp downloaded directly from apachefriends.
As a summary:

Find the socket that mysqld creates for programs to connect to:

```
user@host /opt$ find . -name mysql.sock
/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

add it to your cakePHP database configuration file (cakePHP)/app/Config/database.php

```
'unix_socket' => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

To me, this finally resulted in my cake commands being able to be executed without the "*Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.*".

Answer (score 0):

change login => 'to your user created while setting up the database'. Just make sure the db configuration reflect exactly the same parameters used while creating the database and al should world fine.